# how does vim editor work so fast even with large files? How does it work in the background? How does it process strings?

Tags: string, vim

How does vim or any other text editors process strings in the background? How could they find a set of strings from a large file(say 4GB or more than that) within seconds? What is the logic behind such fast string search?

Comment: The [tag:processing] tag should only be used for questions about the Processing language.

Answer (score 0):

Like most other text editors, Vim still reads the entire file into memory (called *buffer* in Vim). Its search performance therefore depends on your operating system's (virtual) memory handling and the performance of Vim's regular expression engine.

You'll likely get even better performance with tools that don't keep the entire file in memory. Tools like `grep` and `sed` do this, and there are editors that only read in sections of a file, too (though these are typically then labeled "disk editors", not "text editors").